# Get Posts in a Custom Post Type category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have trouble in getting post in a custom post type category. I have code below but it doesnt work well. It still get posts in another category.

```
<?php
    $query= null;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => get_post_type(),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type_cat' => 'featured', // get_post_type() will return post_type, I add _cat -> post_type_cat
        //'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_expiration_date',
                'value' => array(0, current_time('timestamp')),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                )),
            );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template/featured' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template/nofeatured' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What is the category name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such parameter as `post_type_cat`, you want to use either `cat` or if querying posts in a custom taxonomy you would use a taxonomy query.

Category query example;

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

or

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff' );
```

See the following Codex entry for even more ways to query by category;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Taxonomy query example;

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => 'bob' //if field is ID you can reference by cat/term number
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See this entry for more details:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: @djack109 It does work. Please consult https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query. If you are still having issues after this, then consider creating a question so people may assist.

Comment: I got it working, see below

Comment: in this case, is `people` category?

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue `people` is the taxonomy. In WordPress you have `category` which is the default post taxonomy and you have custom taxonomies which enable you to create any other type of taxonomy, like `people` in this case. Best to think of all "categories" in WP as belonging to some form of taxonomy. It can be a little confusing to new comers. So in summary in WP the `category` taxonomy applies to `post_type=post` by default, but it can also be attached to other post types too just like custom taxonomies or you can create a custom taxonomy for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I could not for the life of me get any of the above to work. They either brought back everything or nothing. So after a bit of trial and error, I did this:-

`id` is the slug of the category I want.

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    echo $id;

    $id = get_category_by_slug( $_GET["id"] );

    if (isset($id)) {
        $id = $id->term_id;

        $args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'Products',
            'cat' => $id,
        );
    }
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I'm new to WordPress, having programmed just about every other language, and I have no idea if this is a good or bad way to do things I just know it works for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I wasn't able to find a clear answer. So here is what worked for me:

```
WP_Query version:

$args = array(
    "post_type"      => "story",
    "story-category" =>  $category->slug
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );


get_posts version:

$stories = get_posts([
    "post_type"      =>  "story",
    "story-category" =>  $category->slug       
 ]);
```

It's as simple as that. Just need to pass the custom post type, and then the category slug in a parameter with the same name as the custom post type category slug. I hope this makes sense :)